# What does "keep in touch" imply in "It's been a pleasure talking to you and keep in touch"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "It's been a pleasure talking to you and keep in touch"

Is it just a saying, or does he really mean that he's expecting to receive some information from me in the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Keep in touch" is like "How are you?"

It depends on the context whether the person is using these statements as a mere 'formula' to be polite or whether the person is using these statements to communicate something more genuine.

In most conversations, "Keep in touch" is a mere [nicety](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/nicety) (definition 1.2) and is not meant to be taken literally. In fact, "It's been a pleasure talking to you" can either be a nicety or genuine, or both.

Comment: I agree with everything in your answer except that "keep in touch" means "how are you". *Keep in touch* is used as a **closing**. *How are you* is an **opening** (salutation) that one would use at the start of a conversation. *Keep in touch* is a way of saying *hey, contact me again soon/let's talk again soon*, or something similar. You're right though that a lot of people use it as a polite way of ending a conversation and are often not entirely genuine.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice The answer doesn't say "keep in touch" **means** "how are you"... It's saying they're similar in use, as they are a sort of platitude/small talk - things that people say but don't really mean.

Comment: @Catija You're right, I interpreted the "is like" to mean "synonym of", not "similar to".

Answer (score 3):

"Keep in touch" really means "let's stay in contact."  Whether or not someone is genuine about it doesn't change its meaning.  Some people are actually welcoming future conversations while others can say it and not mean it.